# BufferedReader and File System cache

Tags: java, nio, java-io

[FileChannel documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) claims you can manually put file into FS cache. But `FileChannel` lack of any methods to read file line-by-line. In other hand `BufferedReader` supply you with excellent API to read file line-by-line, but [BufferedReader documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) lack of any note about putting file into FS cache.

*Is `BufferedReader` clever enough to put file into FS cache after the first read?*

Comment: If there is no hint in the documentation it will not use the cache

Comment: I fail to see where in the doc it says you can manually put it into FS cache? I think don't there is an API that you can use to put file in FS cache, it is up to OS to put the file in FS cache, if file is being read all the time and read only, it is usually served from fs cache, FS cache memory is the memory available to OS, not jvm, so if you want to benefit from FS cache, then leave some ram for OS as well, not giving all available ram to JVM, so OS can use fs cache and make read operations blazing fast.

Comment: @Elbek right, by "manually put file into FS cache"  I meant there is an API, means that's up to you whether to put something into FS cache

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk There is no api, mapping file portion to memory is not the same as putting it in fs cache. the reason is, once you map it is you who manages that section and deallocate that section (btw java lacks that functionality, it has no deallocation method), while fs cache is fully transparent and os takes care of maintaining it. Can you point an api method you think it will do.

Comment: @Elbek please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622471/how-to-make-use-of-the-filesystem-cache-in-java-or-python/26670654#26670654. See bottom line of the answer for API method reference

Comment: The `map()` method "maps a region of this channel's file directly into memory".  This does not mean the file has been moved into memory (or cache).  It means **when** the virtual address is accessed, the file will be read from the file system to that virtual address space, according to the given mapping.  But it does not claim the entire mapped address space is always realized with the file; the OS could do this 1 page at a time, on demand, and only hold 1 page of the file in memory at a time.

Comment: @AJNeufeld than how Lucene can be sure to read everything from FS cache?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk, Lucene is not sure either, that is why lucene engineers advise you to have ram available to os (again not for jvm) so os can put term dictionary and posting file in fs to have best performance. but this is not required, lucene will work fine without having them in fs cache too, but will be slower. As you see lucene cannot force OS to put files in fs cache, but lucene segments are read only and being accessed lots of time, os automatically puts them in fs cache if there is room.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  Long answer: if the OS is not running other memory hungry applications, and you memory map the file, the OS might read the entire file into memory.  More likely, the OS won't read the entire file into memory, but waits until the first access.  At that point, the OS would read the accessed section of the file into that block of memory.  How much is read depends on the page size.  Which pages are read depends entirely on which pages are accessed; the first pages will not be read to memory if accessing starts at the 1GB point in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a `BufferedReader` from a `FileChannel`, but you could experiment with the following to see if it gets you close to what you're looking for:

```
File file = ...;
long pos = 0;
long size = file.length();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, pos, size);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

However, there is no guarantee that the `FileInputStream` will be reading from the memory mapped to the `MappedByteBuffer`.  If it does, it might not on a different operating system.  YMMV.